# Stretch inner span upto it's outer parent div space, but inner span should be scaled upto outer div height width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div with width 200px and height 500px, and there is span inside div with having a text "99", i want it would be stretch upto outer div space

```
<div style="width:200px;height:500px;display:inline-block"><span>99</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added transform:scale(x,y) property to meet the expectation. adjust the scale value how you want. thanks

```css
div{border:2px solid}


span{
display:inline-block;
    transform: scale(11.1,25);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:500px;display:inline-block">
<span>99</span>
</div>
```

Comment: need to stretched with inner content of span